# How to select multiple divs with Lasso Selection Tool

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have multiple div's on my HTML page, and want to create a selection tool to be able to select a subset of those divs (and afterwards simply add a class to those divs or whatever). It could select every div that falls within the selected area (or maybe only the ones which center fall within the selected area), like so:

[image: Selection]

How would I go about this? I looked into jQuery UI's `.selectable()`, but that's not quite what I'm looking for since it has a rectangle as selection box, not a freeform one.

I made a JSFiddle of what I want, but how do I create the lasso line?

http://jsfiddle.net/aesafjcy/4/

```
tool_active = false;
select_active = false;

$(".btn-select").click(function() {
  tool_active = !tool_active;
  $(this).toggleClass("btn-active");
  $("html").toggleClass("select-active");
});

$("html").mousedown(function(e) {
  if(tool_active && e.target.id != "selection_tool") {
    select_active = true;
  }
});

$("html").mouseup(function(e) {
  if(select_active) {
    select_active = !select_active;
  }
});

$("html").mousemove(function(e) {
  if(select_active && $(e.target).hasClass('box')) {
    $(e.target).addClass("box-selected");
  }
});
```

Comment: You could try detect the position of the mouse each time it moves, and if it is hovering over any of the divs you want to select, add a class to them?

Comment: I made a JSFiddle, but how do I get the lasso line? http://jsfiddle.net/aesafjcy/3/

Comment: Are you happy with using a jQuery plugin? If not there is another way to do it, but it is easier with the plugin.

Comment: Sure, I don't mind that, what plugin?

Comment: Actually, just worked it out, no plugin needed. Posting an answer........

Comment: Does that answer your question? If so, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

For the selection part, you can detect the position of the mouse each time it moves, and if it is hovering over any of the divs, select them (add a class `.selected`)

To create the line, you will need to check wether the selection tool is active, AND the mouse is down. If they are, place a `1px` by `1px` (or whatever thickness of line you want) div, absolutely positioned, and set `top` and `left` properties the the current mouse position. This can be done with the following code:

```
// On mouse move
$("html").mousemove(function(e) {

    // If the tool is active, and the mouse is down
    if (tool_is_active == true && select_active == true) {
        // Append a div that represents the drawn line
        $('body').append('<div class="selectionline"></div>')

        // Set the CSS for that div, to position it where the mouse is
        $('.selectionline:last-child').css({
            'left': e.pageX + "px",
            'top': e.pageY + "px",
        })
    }
});
```

I edited your JSFiddle to have the line drawn when selecting - [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/nbsgkt3q/)

There is one problem with drawing this line, there are gaps. This is because the `mousemove` function detects when the mouse stops moving for a fraction of a second, not for each pixels it moves by.

You could try a `setTimeout()` to detect every millisecond, and remove the gaps in the line.

Comment: I understand what you're doing, but this does not add any div's that are not touched but are still inside the selection.

Comment: Oh, so you want to select everything _inside_ the drawn shape! That is practically impossible. You could make a long script to go pixel-line by pixel-line, and check if there is anything between 2 divs (the drawn lines), and if there is, select it. But you would also have to make sure there are only 2 drawn-divs on each line, which would be hard. All in all, it will take about 10 hours!

Comment: Of course, like the Lasso Selection Tool (see title!). I don't think it's impossible I have seen it done before.

Comment: @appel Do you know where you saw it, then you could check out their code?